# FFMPEG not creating thumbnails

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg, html5-video, thumbnails

My ffmpeg command in php is

```
echo $cmd_thumbnail_create = ("\"$ffmpeg\" -i \"" . $dir.$videopath . "\" -an -ss $getFromSecond \"" . $dir.$thumbnailpath ."\"");
exec($cmd_thumbnail_create);
```

Output of which is

> "C:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg" -i "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/uploaded_videos/intro_en.mp4" -an -ss 6 "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/thumbnail/intro_en.jpg"

This when copied and executed on the command prompt creates the thumbnail at proper location with proper name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try changing exec($cmd_thumbnail_create); to shell_exec($cmd_thumbnail_create); and see if it works

Comment: @Satya  Nopes, sorry it does not work like that.!!

Comment: this is what is working for me on one of my servers shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$physicalname ." -f image2 -vframes 1 ". $imagename);

Comment: edit your command to ("ffmpeg -i " . $dir.$videopath . " -an -ss $getFromSecond " . $dir.$thumbnailpath );

Comment: The \" are added to fight the spaces that happen to occur in the video name

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...
 first.... locate your path to FFMPEG
mine is 
     `$ffmpeg = "H:\\SERVr\\htdocs\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";`
Then.. in your shell_exec...
`shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i your-input.jpg -an -ss 30 -s 120x100 your-output.jpg 2>&1");`

-i is your input file.
-ss is video time you want the clip pulled from.
-s is the size of the thumbnail you want
This works on my Windows machine with XAMPP, and works perfectly.